InvalidURI: MongoDB URI options are key=value pairs
I'm getting the above error even though my URI is properly formatted and was working a while ago as well. I made no changes to the URI, but I did install some packages using pip.
Here is a redacted version of my URI-
"mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0.example.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

And here is the full error-
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\User\Work\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\uri_parser.py", line 336, in split_options
    raise ValueError
ValueError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\User\Work\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "D:\User\Work\Project\app\pages\file.py", line 8, in <module>
    from utils.display_document import display_document
  File "D:\User\Work\Project\utils\display_document.py", line 12, in <module>
    mongodb = MongoDB(COLLECTION)
  File "D:\User\Work\Project\MongoDB.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.client = MongoClient(MONGODB_URI)
  File "D:\User\Work\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 736, in __init__
    res = uri_parser.parse_uri(
  File "D:\User\Work\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\uri_parser.py", line 511, in parse_uri
    options.update(split_options(opts, validate, warn, normalize))
  File "D:\User\Work\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\uri_parser.py", line 338, in split_options
    raise InvalidURI("MongoDB URI options are key=value pairs.")
pymongo.errors.InvalidURI: MongoDB URI options are key=value pairs.


Does your password contain any special characters like $ : / ? # [ ] @?

@WernfriedDomscheit It does, but I ensured that it was properly encoded. Also this URI was working perfectly fine a while ago, until I did some other installations using pip.

Well, according to the error message it looks like that it is not properly encoded. How did you encode the URI? Maybe try to change the password without these characters.

If you are okay with changing passwords, try https://1337.me/, this will not add any speacial characters while adding complexities.
Hoping that according to documentation of https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/ which clearly states that the percent encoding is done correctly.
